# Cannot use __file__ when running startup file in IDLE's normal mode

Tags: python, python-idle

I've written a little batch file (Windows 8.1) to start my script directly in IDLE:

```
START "" pythonw.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.py" -r my_script.py
```

The script contains the line

```
my_dir = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
```

which produces a name error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "my_script.py", line 245, in out_file_dia
    my_dir = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

If I open IDLE first and then start the script, it works fine. Why is

```
__file__
```

not defined in this situation?

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: Interesting question.  I reproduced with command `python -m idlelib.idle -r f:/python/a/tem2.py`, where `python` runs 3.8.0 repository build, and `tem2.py` contains `print(__name__, __file__)`.  The latter ran fine from editor.  If I add `-n` before `-r`, so that tem2.py executes in the IDLE process, __file__ is the IDLE process file `.../idlelib/idle.py`.  `set PYTHONSTARTUP=f:/python/a/tem2.py` followed by `python` prints `__main__ f:/python/a/tem2.py`.  `>>> __file__` results in the exception.  Python sets __file__ for startup file, unsets in interactive input.  IDLE does not.  Bug.

Comment: I'm using 3.6.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In interactive mode, the input 'file' is the stream of statements entered by the user, so `__file__` is left unset.  If there is a PYTHONSTARTUP file, `__file__` is set to that filename while the file is run, then unset before the first `>>>` prompt.  Currently, IDLE does not do this when running user code in a separate process, which is now the normal mode.

I opened https://bugs.python.org/issue32984 to fix this.  I will try to remember to report here when it is.

When IDLE is started with -n, to use the old deprecated mode in which user code is executed in the IDLE GUI process, startup files and interactive input see `__file__` set to an idlelib file.  Both are wrong but will not be fixed.

EDIT: [PR-5981](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/5981), which works for me on Windows, modifies pyshell.execfile to begin as follows:

```
def execfile(self, filename, source=None):  # currently line 633
    "Execute an existing file"
    if source is None:
        with tokenize.open(filename) as fp:
            source = fp.read()
            if use_subprocess:
                source = (f"__file__ = r'''{os.path.abspath(filename)}'''\n"
                          + source + "\ndel __file__")
```

The last 3 lines are new.  uwain12345, adding them should solve your problem.  If not, I would like to know.

EDIT 2: tweek replacement code to allow for ' in startup file name.

Note: f strings are new in 3.6.  For older Pythons, replace the `source` line with

```
                filename = os.path.abspath(filename)
                source = ("__file__ = r'''{}'''\n".format(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks. I must admit I'm a bit reluctant to muck about in my Python installation.

Comment: Caution is good.  Upgrading to 3.6.5-32 when it is released will copy a new version of pyshell.py, with this fix, into your 3.6 directory.  If you do not want to wait, adding 3 lines is about as safe as anything.  *Copy* pyshell.py to pyshell.bak, edit pyshell.py by inserting 3 lines, save, and test.  If necessary, rename pyshell.bak to pyshell.py.  If you, or a Windows or disk glitch messes up python36-32/, run repair.  I always keep the most recent installation file in a downloads directory in case this is needed.